# Java results differ for (int)Math.pow(2,x) and 1<<x

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Why do the following two operations yield different results in Java for `x = 31` or `32` but the same results for `x=3`?

```
int x=3;
int b = (int) Math.pow(2,x);
int c = 1<<x;
```

Results:

```
x=32: b=2147483647; c=1;
x=31: b=2147483647; c=-2147483648;
x=3:  b=8         ; c=8
```

Comment: A subtle difference is that pow() is **much** slower even if the answer is the same. pow() has rounding error, whereas `int` has overflow.  You can try `1L << 32` which equals `2147483648`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are multiple issues at play:

- An `int` can only store values between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`.
- `1 << x` only [uses the lowest five bits of `x`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19). Thus, `1 << 32` is by definition the same as `1 << 0`.
- Shift operations are performed on the [two's-complement integer representation of the value of the left operand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19); this explains why `1 << 31` is negative.
- `Math.pow(2, 32)` returns a `double`.
- `(int)(d)`, where `d` is a `double` greater than `2147483647` returns `2147483647` (["the largest representable value of type `int`"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

What this interview question does is show that `(int)Math.pow(2, x)` and `1 << x` are not equivalent for values of `x` outside the `0`...`30` range.

P.S. It is perhaps interesting to note that using `long` in place of `int` (and `1L` in place of `1`) would give yet another set of results different from the other two. This holds even if the final results are converted to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation `Math.pow` will promote both of its arguments to double and return double. Obviously when the returned result is double and you cast it to int you'll get only the highest 32 bits and the rest will be truncated - hence you always get the `(int) Math.pow(2,x);` value. When you do bitshift you always work with ints and hence an overflow occurs.

Comment: I'm guessing the highest 32 bits of the mantissa. I might be mistaken though.

Comment: Hm, okay, that might be true. I just remembered it to always return `2^31-1`. Removed the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the limits of the type int. How large a number can it hold?

Comment: The question is about the difference between left shift and explicit powers of 2.

Comment: And add to the limit of `int` the fact that it's a signed type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a micro-benchmark for the case of a long. On my laptop (2.8GHz), using shift instead of `Math.pow` is over 7x faster.

```java
int limit = 50_000_000;
@Test
public void testPower() {
    Random r = new Random(7);
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        int p = r.nextInt(63);
        long l = (long)Math.pow(2,p);
    }
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((t1-t)/1000.0); // 3.758 s
}
@Test
public void testShift() {
    Random r = new Random(7);
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        int p = r.nextInt(63);
        long l = 1L << p;
    }
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((t1-t)/1000.0); // 0.523 s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int is 32 bits in size and since it is signed (by default), the first bit is used for the sign. When you shift left 31 bits, you get the [Two's Compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement), which is -(2^32). When you shift left 32 bits, it just loops all the way back around to 1. If you were to do this shifting with longs instead of ints, you would get the answers you expect (that is until you shift 63+ bits).