# Java - NumberFormatException. Convert long bynary string to dec

Tags: java, binary

I want to convert binary string to dec.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("000011011111110111000001110000111110", 2));
     }
}
```

I get error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "000011011111110111000001110000111110".
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The value you are trying to parse is not a valid integer in java.

Comment: why? is not a valid integer in java

Comment: How can i convert long binary string to int?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492711/java-convert-byte-to-integer

Comment: Try adding this line `int x = 000011011111110111000001110000111110;` to a method, read the error then you will know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Long.parseLong` for the string in your question, still you may find a limit in that also, so you have to implement different logic.

You can have a method that convert the binary string to integer.

```
public static long binaryToInteger(String binaryString) {
    char[] chars = binaryString.toCharArray();
    long resultInt = 0;
    int placeHolder = 0;
    for (int i=chars.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (chars[i]=='1') {
          resultInt += Math.pow(2,placeHolder);
        }
        placeHolder++;
    }
    return resultInt;
}
```

Comment: `Math.pow(2, placeHolder)` can return wrong value since it returns `double` and you're casting it to `int`. It's better to use `1 << placeholder`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416694/java-results-differ-for-intmath-pow2-x-and-1x

Comment: This is most efficient:
'long r=0;
for (int i=0; i<chars.length; ++i)
  r=r<<1+chars[i]-'0';
return r`

Answer (score 3):

Short solution - [Integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) simply don't go that high. That's not an int.

[`ParseInt()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) documentation mentions, you recieve a string and a radix, and get back the result of the convertion. However, integers are 4 bytes = 32 bits, and thus range from `-(2^31)` to `2^31-1`, and your number - `11011111110111000001110000111110`, is in fact [32](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/strlen/) bits long - which means, it's bigger than the maximal value. Thus, the function throws this [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) - this is not a valid value for an int.

If you'd like to fix it, I'd use a [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), like described [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492711/java-convert-byte-to-integer)

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(myArray);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);  // if you want little-endian
int result = buffer.getShort(); // use with a bigInteger instead. you could use any of the bytebuffer functions described in the link :)
```

Comment: "However, integers are 32 bytes"...?

Comment: I was having one of personal moments where I thought I'd been wrong for the past 5 years! :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BigInteger` class and store the number as `long`:

```
BigInteger bigInt=new BigInteger("000011011111110111000001110000111110");
long a=bigInt.longValue();
```

The value you are going to store is too big for `int` and does not fall inside the range the type `int` can hold(`-(2^31)` to `2^31-1`).So it throws `NumberFormatException`.`long` is a suitable option here.